# How to Split rows to different columns in Spark DataFrame/DataSet?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

Suppose I have data set like :

```
Name | Subject | Y1  | Y2 
A    | math    | 1998| 2000
B    |         | 1996| 1999
     | science | 2004| 2005
```

I want to split rows of this data set such that Y2 column will be eliminated like :

```
Name | Subject | Y1
A    | math    | 1998
A    | math    | 1999
A    | math    | 2000
B    |         | 1996
B    |         | 1997
B    |         | 1998
B    |         | 1999
     | science | 2004
     | science | 2005
```

Can someone suggest something here ? I hope I had made my query clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @cheseaux why did you delete your answer ? It seemed valid to me.

Answer (score 4):

I think you only need to create an `udf` to create the range. Then you can use explode to create the necessary rows:

```
val createRange = udf { (yearFrom: Int, yearTo: Int) =>
    (yearFrom to yearTo).toList
}

df.select($"Name", $"Subject", functions.explode(createRange($"Y1", $"Y2"))).show()
```

EDIT: The python version of this code would be something like:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, explode
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

createRange=udf( lambda (yearFrom, yearTo): list(range(yearFrom, yearTo)), IntegerType())

df.select($"Name", $"Subject", explode(createRange($"Y1", $"Y2"))).show()
```

Comment: Can we do it using python pandas ? I am not able to understand your spark code.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested this code in pyspark and it works as expected:

```
data= sc.parallelize([["A","math",1998,2000],["B","",1996,1999],["","science",2004,2005]]

data.map(lambda reg: ((reg[0],reg[1]),(range(reg[2],reg[3]+1))) )
    .flatMapValues(lambda reg: reg).collect()
```

In more detail, you need to convert the input data to  a pair RDD in the form (key,value), where key is composed with the first two fields, since the result will be flattened keeping the key intact with `flatMapValues`. The values to be mapped are constructed as a `range` from `Y1` to `Y2`. All of this is done in the first `map`.

`flatMapValues` will return each of the values in the `range` associated to its `key`.

The output looks like this:

```
[(('A', 'math'), 1998),
 (('A', 'math'), 1999),
 (('A', 'math'), 2000),
 (('B', ''), 1996),
 (('B', ''), 1997),
 (('B', ''), 1998),
 (('B', ''), 1999),
 (('', 'science'), 2004),
 (('', 'science'), 2005)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way in which you can implement this :

```
  val resultantDF= df.rdd.flatMap{row =>
    val rangeInitial = row.getInt(2)
    val rangeEnd = row.getInt(3)
    val array = rangeInitial to rangeEnd
    (List.fill(array.size)(row.getString(0)),List.fill(array.size)(row.getString(1)),array).zipped.toList
    }.toDF("Name","Subject","Y1")

resultantDF.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use spark select easily to get what you want in a Data frame, or even in RDD.

```
Dataset<Row> sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT Name,Subject,Y1 FROM tableName");
```

if you are starting from already exesting Data frame, say users, you can use something like this:

```
resultDF = usersDF.select("Name","Subject","Y1");
```

Comment: See the output. The main purpose is to split rows in number of times as (Y2-Y1) and not just deleting Y2.

Comment: i want to split rows on the basis of range of year
for eg if data is like
``A  |  math |1998 | 2000`
then the output would be like
           `A  |  math| 1998
           A  | math | 1999
           A  |  math| 2000`

Comment: `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val toRange = udf { (y1: Int, y2: Int) => (y1 to y2).toArray }

input
 .withColumn("years", toRange($"Y1", $"Y2"))
 .select($"Name", explode($"years") as "Year")`

But it is showing NumberFormatException : null, due to presence of null values.